# Validation Logic - MicroService client

Tags: validation, web, design-patterns, client, microservices

My Java application invokes a third-party microservice to perform some business operations.

In most use cases, the third-party service accepts users' personally-identifiable information (PII) and returns a matching consumer entry. If any input is missing, the service returns an error through some error code and error message pattern. Since it's a third-party service, we do not control those errors.

My question is, should my own application perform validation for the input parameters before invoking the third-party service or rely on that service's validation?

**Benefits with the 1st approach that I see:**

- Full control over validation
- Clean error handling, because we can attach specific error messages with validation logic
- If input data is not valid, we can avoid calling services

**Benefits with the 2nd approach that I see:**

- Caller need not worry about the validation logic
- We can completely rely on services to provide error messages/codes that Caller can print in the error logs to indicate errors.

Comment: How does your app obtain the PII? From a database, or another service, or your own clients?

Comment: Thanks for editing. My app obtains PII from two sources. A part of the PII (for example First Name, Last Name, DOB etc) comes from the database that my application invokes through Hibernate, and another part of the PII (Address details) comes from a microservice hosted internally that my app invokes through Rest Client.

Comment: It sounds like the PII is coming from trusted sources, in which case I would say you needn't re-validate it inside your own app.

Comment: But if I do not, will this be a good idea to rely on validation of third-party service? I mean in the cases where my own services or database returns a value that is empty/null (and that's mandatory for third-party service).

Answer (score 0):

Let try to search some `rule base enginee` and see which one is fit with your model